# Confusion related to minimization of a gaussian likelihood function

Tags: normal-distribution, optimization, covariance

I have this confusion related to minimization of gaussian likelihood function. The negative of the log likelihood of gaussian distribution is

$-\log \det(Q) + \text{tr}(SQ) + \lambda||Q||_{1}$ where $Q$ is the precision matrix to be estimated

I am following this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.5479v2.pdf)

It's been mentioned that

Using sub-gradient notation, we can write the optimality conditions (aka “normal equations”) for a solution to the above equation as

$-Q^{-1} + S + \lambda\Gamma = 0$

where $\Gamma_{jk} = \text{sign}(Q_{jk})$ if $Q_{jk} \neq 0$
and

$\Gamma_{jk} \in [-1, 1]$ if $Q_{jk} = 0$

I didn't get how come

$\Gamma_{jk} \in [-1, 1]$ if $Q_{jk} = 0$

Can anyone please explain it should be 0 isn't it. I didn't get how the interval $[-1, 1]$ came

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The equation says that, at the minimum, one of the subgradients 
of 
$$-\log \det Q + \text{tr}( S Q ) + \lambda \| Q \|_1$$
is zero.

The last term, $\lambda \Gamma$ is a subgradient of $\lambda \left\| Q \right\|_1$.
Since $\left\| Q \right\|_1 = \sum_{ij} \left| Q_{ij} \right|$,
we just have to find the subgradients of 
the 1-dimensional function $f(q) = \left| q \right|$.
If $q \neq 0$, $f$ is differentiable, and there is only one subgradient: $f'(q) = \text{sign}\,q$.
For $q=0$, any number in $[-1,1]$ is a subgradient.